# Number of new jobs associated with a saved search don't update across browsers

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Jobs has saved searches now! (Yay!). However, the nice little number pill indicating how many new jobs fall into the saved search no longer applies across browsers, like the automatically created searches used to do.

This means if I check jobs on my laptop in the morning and then check again on my desktop that night, I see a count indicating all of the postings I already saw.

For example I see this right now on my desktop:

[image: Saved Job pills]

Those bottom two don't have anything new since I looked this morning on my laptop. The 10 and 27 ones have a few new ones since this morning, but not 37 total.

Can the Jobs saved searches indicator be synchronized across a user account instead of per browser?

---

A day later, [this is what I see on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXZyD.png).  I visited all of those saved searches yesterday. Compared to the picture above, it looks like I should only see a few new ones, not these big numbers.

Comment: Do you not see the updated number of jobs even when you refresh the page? Or are you asking about refreshing the number of jobs even if you don't refresh the page? We don't use cookies for this, so it should already be synchronized by account.

Comment: I am saying that I looked at jobs in Firefox on my laptop 8 hours ago. 1 hour ago I looked at jobs again but this time in Firefox on my desktop. The screenshot above is what I saw on the desktop. The "new" jobs that it says are available I saw this morning on my other machine. A refresh of the page did not reduce the count. I needed to go to each of the searches to eliminate the count that was shown on the desktop.

Comment: @AurélienGasser As an example, this is what I see right now on my phone. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXZyD.png  I visited all of those saved searches yesterday. Compared to the picture in my original question, it looks like I should only see a few new ones, not these big numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: it's fixed.**

The logic was:

1. never show a "new jobs count" badge if you have viewed this search within the last hour.
2. otherwise, compute the number of jobs that were posted *since the saved search was created*, and cache that number for an hour.

The condition in item 2. was incorrect: it should be "since the saved search was last *viewed*" and not "since the saved search was *created*".

So, it didn't have much to do with changing device, and everything to do with time passing (and cache expiring). I'm honestly not sure how we missed this (significant) bug until now.

It is now fixed, please allow for up to 1 hour before before changes are active.

Thank you for your report, and please let us know if you see incorrect counts again.